# How do you use sql count to find the number of position control numbers for each person in this query?

Tags: sql, group-by, count, subquery, aggregate-functions

I am trying to count the number of position control numbers for each employee. I tried using SELECT COUNT(hrp.pos_ctl_no), but its only returning the count for each position control number and not the count of the position control numbers for each person. In the example result provided , Abbott Edith has 2 position control numbers. I only want her to appear once in the spreadsheet with a count of 2 by her name to indicate that she has 2 position control numbers. Instead it is showing her twice because of the 2 different control numbers.

Here is my sql query:

```
SELECT COUNT(hrp.pos_ctl_no),
empm.empl_no as "Employee Number",
hr.last_name as "Last Name", 
hr.first_name as "First Name",
isnull(hr.mid_name, '') as "Middle Name",
cctr.cctr_desc as "Work Location",
sj_desc as "Job Title",
code.st_job_cd as "Job Code",
hrp.pos_ctl_no as "Position Control Number"

FROM cenoff.hrperson hr
JOIN cenoff.prempm empm on empm.pers_id = hr.pers_id
JOIN [NGSQLSVR].[CENOFF].[PREMPJOB] job on job.empl_no = empm.empl_no
JOIN [NGSQLSVR].[CENOFF].[CCTR] cctr on cctr.glcval_val = job.glcval_val
JOIN [NGSQLSVR].[CENOFF].[PREMPCPI] CPI on cpi.empl_no = empm.empl_no
JOIN [NGSQLSVR].[CENOFF].[hrstpcode] code on code.st_job_cd = cpi.st_job_cd
JOIN [NGSQLSVR].[CENOFF].[pretype] on pretype.empl_type = job.empl_type
LEFT JOIN [NGSQLSVR].[CENOFF].[hrpcej] hrp on hrp.pers_id = hr.pers_id


WHERE 
job.job_type = 'P'
and cpi.assign_perc = '1.0000'
and job.job_no = '1'
--and hrp.pos_ctl_no is NULL
and empm.cpi_stat = 'A'  
--and cctr.cctr_desc = 'Isabella Complex'

GROUP BY 
empm.empl_no,
hrp.pos_ctl_no,
hr.last_name,
hr.first_name, 
isnull(hr.mid_name, ''), 
cctr.cctr_desc,
sj_desc,
code.st_job_cd, 
pretype.empl_type_desc, 
cpi.assign_perc, 
job.job_no, 
hr.hr_stat_cd, 
empm.cpi_stat, 
empm.hr_stat_cd,
job.hr_stat_cd, 
pos_began,
hrp.pos_ended, 
job.hire_date, 
enroll_end_date, 
contr_end_date 

ORDER BY hr.last_name, hr.first_name
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwoq3.png)

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. your GROUP BY list looks very long.

Answer (score 0):

Without the data it's very difficult to understand. Removing **pos_ctl_no** from group by clause might do the trick.

```
SELECT COUNT(hrp.pos_ctl_no),
empm.empl_no as "Employee Number",
hr.last_name as "Last Name", 
hr.first_name as "First Name",
isnull(hr.mid_name, '') as "Middle Name",
cctr.cctr_desc as "Work Location",
sj_desc as "Job Title",
code.st_job_cd as "Job Code",


FROM cenoff.hrperson hr
JOIN cenoff.prempm empm on empm.pers_id = hr.pers_id
JOIN [NGSQLSVR].[CENOFF].[PREMPJOB] job on job.empl_no = empm.empl_no
JOIN [NGSQLSVR].[CENOFF].[CCTR] cctr on cctr.glcval_val = job.glcval_val
JOIN [NGSQLSVR].[CENOFF].[PREMPCPI] CPI on cpi.empl_no = empm.empl_no
JOIN [NGSQLSVR].[CENOFF].[hrstpcode] code on code.st_job_cd = cpi.st_job_cd
JOIN [NGSQLSVR].[CENOFF].[pretype] on pretype.empl_type = job.empl_type
LEFT JOIN [NGSQLSVR].[CENOFF].[hrpcej] hrp on hrp.pers_id = hr.pers_id


WHERE 
job.job_type = 'P'
and cpi.assign_perc = '1.0000'
and job.job_no = '1'
--and hrp.pos_ctl_no is NULL
and empm.cpi_stat = 'A'  
--and cctr.cctr_desc = 'Isabella Complex'

GROUP BY 
empm.empl_no,
hr.last_name,
hr.first_name, 
isnull(hr.mid_name, ''), 
cctr.cctr_desc,
sj_desc,
code.st_job_cd, 


ORDER BY hr.last_name, hr.first_name
```

Comment: Please view the result link. I dont know how to post the screenshot of the results.

Comment: No , after removing that, people are still appearing twice due to having multiple position control numbers.

Comment: Please try my edited answer and let me know your feedback

Comment: if it's still not working you may mail me your sample data in kmnur@hotmail.com

Comment: Only empm.empl_no,
hr.last_name,
hr.first_name, 
isnull(hr.mid_name, ''), 
cctr.cctr_desc,
sj_desc and 
code.st_job_cd columns are in select list without any aggregation so it's a possibility that you want to group the result by only those columns.

Comment: Nvm I excluded it in the select statement

Comment: Any column from those might have duplicate values which were causing multiple rows instead of one.

Comment: If your problem has been resolve please accept this answer by clicking the green check. Best wishes.